# Pseudo-isomorphism symmetric for torsion modules in Iwasawa theory

Tags: modules, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Lambda=\mathbb Z _p[[ T]]$ be the ring of power series over the $p$-adic integers, and let $X$ and $Y$ be $\Lambda$-modules. We say that $X$ is **pseudo-isomorphic** to $Y$ if there exists a $\Lambda$-module morphism $f:X\to Y$ with finite kernel and cokernel.

It is mentioned in the literature (e.g. Lang's Cyclotomic Fields) that pseudo-isomorphism is symmetric for torsion $\Lambda$-modules. Neither of the aforementioned books provide a proof. Is there something elementary I'm missing?

(Note that in general, pseudo-isomorphism is not symmetric: consider $X=(p,T)$ and $Y=\Lambda$. Then the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow Y$ is a pseudo-isomorphism, but every morphism $Y\to X$ has infinite cokernel.)

Comment: It's somewhat buried in the standard proof of the structure of *finitely generated* torsion modules that this holds for these. Do these sources explicitly claim it is true for non-finitely-generated torsion modules as well?

Comment: Thank you, now I see how this follows for finitely generated torsion modules. 

For example, Iwasawa writes in On $\mathbb Z_l$-Extensions of Algebraic Number Fields (1973) that this holds for $\Lambda$-modules as well, and so does Rubin in the appendix of Lang's book (Lemma 6.5). However, neither emphasises that this would be true for non-finitely generated modules, so it is possible that this condition is implied.

Comment: Also it appears that I was wrong about Washington, he states this for finitely generated $\Lambda$-modules only.